# Check web content changed (OSM-tile, python)

Tags: python, urllib2, openstreetmap

In my Python code I'm downloading tiles form Openstreetmap (OSM). For Performance and traffic reason, they are stored in an temp storage. However before reusing this data, I want to check if this data is still up-to-date.

This is how simple download is done:

```
import urllib2

# Normal import without Version control:
url = r"http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/1/1/1.png"
imgstr = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

I'm searching something likle this (pseudo code)

```
imgstr = ...        # Value from database
local_version = ... # Value from database
online_version = getolineversionnumber(url)
if not(online_version==local_verion):
    imgstr = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    version = online_version
```

is there such a function like `getolineversionnumber`?

**Question answered by hint of scai. No more answers required. **

Comment: What's wrong with the Last-Modified header?

Comment: How do i acess this header with Python? I couldn't find the appropriate function in urllib2.  What command shall i google?

Comment: Ok. I'll try to acess it like in the example below. Thank you for the keyword 'lastmodified header'. http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/etags.html

Comment: Also please check OSM's [tile usage policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy).

Comment: Thanks for this hint. No compliance problem here.   its more an hobby project for training python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice, to post answers to own questions for other readers. Here is what I have learned.

The property which i was searching is called etag (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag).
and accessed like:

```
import urllib2
url = r"http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/1/1/1.png"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
firstdatastream = opener.open(request)
online_version=firstdatastream.headers.dict['etag']
```